# Microsoft Graph API - Email sent to new users

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

We're using the [MS Graph API to create users](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users#create-user) on our Office 365 tenant which is a domain managed outside of Office 365. (e.g. users.ourcompany.com)

Since we're autogenerating the password for the users, we would like them to be aware of that password that they could use to login for the first time and reset it.

Does this API automatically trigger an email (containing their username and password) to the address as specified by the `userPrincipalName` user attribute? If not, is there a way to do it explicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the admin creating a new user has an Exchange Online mailbox provisioned, you could [send an email](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_sendmail) from that account using Graph.

Comment: Nice, this is helpful! Do all the Office 365 subscriptions come with an Exchange Online sku? Just looking to see that the organization has purchased an Office 365 plan that doesn't have the Exchange capability. Also, the example in the documentation linked, the email address has a subdomain belonging to `onmicrosoft.com`. Is it just an example or is it only limited to that domain?

Comment: O365 includes a [wide array of SKUs and many](https://products.office.com/en-us/business/compare-more-office-365-for-business-plans), but not all, include Exchange Online. Also, some orgs may have a mix of users with Exchange Online, Exchange On-Prem and non-Exchange mailboxes. In this case, if all outgoing emails are coming from a single account then only that account would require Exchange Online.

Comment: The onmicrosoft.com domain is provided to all O365 tenants when they are created. If you use a custom domain as the primary, onmicrosoft.com would be some a secondary (alternative) domain. So the primary "mydomain.com" would also have "mydomain.onmicrosoft.com" as a secondary domain.

Comment: Sure, I understand that. But if you send an email, with the `fromAddress` belonging to the admin, say, `admin@mydomain.onmicrosoft.com`, can the `toAddress` be something like `someuser@users.mydomain.com`?